# large chunks of text went missing

Tags: customization

We are trying to solve a little mystery.

We have an old WordPress website with many customizations and thousands of pages. We try to keep it updated as much as possible.

Recently a quite annoying issue start to surface.

Our most important webpages are organized with tiles: large chunk of texts with customized styling.
Recently, in the past weeks it seems that large chunks of text went missing, both from the backend and the frontend. They just disappear. We are not aware of when it happens, so this leaves us vulnerable to heavy drops in user engagement and SEO positioning.

We are looking for some ideas of possible causes. Any hint?

Best Regard

L.